# Weighted and directed network computation in Mathematica

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is there any set of commands in Mathematica to compute mean shortest path, global clustering coefficient, diameter and radius of the network, etc. for weighted and/or directed graphs? There indeed exists commands which work for undirected and unweighted graphs but not sure for the above graphs.

Answer (score 3):

That does not seem to be possible. I just tried `FindShortestTour`:

Undirected case:

```
g = Graph[{UndirectedEdge[1, 2]}];

FindShortestTour[g]
(* {2, {1, 2, 1}} *)
```

Directed case:

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2}];

FindShortestTour[g]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Fail! Perhaps working around this using the `DistanceFunction` option? The idea would be to provide directions using ans asymmetric adjacency matrix:

```
h = (AdjacencyMatrix[g] // Normal) /. 0 -> Infinity
(* {{∞, 1}, {∞, ∞}} *)

FindShortestTour[Range@Length@h, DistanceFunction -> (h[[#1, #2]] &)]
```

> During evaluation of FindShortestTour::asymdi: The distance function must be symmetric. >>

```
(* {} *)
```

This clearly shows that `FindShortestTour` expects only undirected graphs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Most of the commands for graphs should be expected to work on directed graphs.

Below is some example code.

Generate a graph:

```
cgr = ButterflyGraph[2]
```

Make a directed graph with weighted edges:

```
arules = Most[ArrayRules[AdjacencyMatrix[cgr]]];
arules[[All, 2]] = RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length[arules]];
arules[[RandomChoice[Range[Length[arules]], 
    Floor[0.3*Length[arules]]], 2]] = 0;

wgrMat = SparseArray[
   Append[Select[arules, #[[2]] > 0 &], {_, _} -> \[Infinity]]];
wgr = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[wgrMat];
```

Find shortest path:

```
FindShortestPath[wgr, 1, 6]

(* Out[266]= {1, 8, 12, 11, 4, 5, 6} *)
```

Find different parameters of the graph:

```
Through[{GraphDiameter, GraphRadius, GraphCenter}[wgr]]

(* Out[267]= {3.55888, 1.81135, {11}} *)
```

Find distances between nodes:

```
GraphDistanceMatrix[wgr] // MatrixForm
```

The results above are for this graph:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For almost any graph-related function, *check the documentation*, and open the Details section.  At the bottom you'll find something like:

> `EdgeBetweennessCentrality` works with undirected graphs, directed graphs, weighted graphs, multigraphs, and mixed graphs.

So the answer is: **you have to look this up individually for every function**.

Comment: The FindShortestTour Details section does not mention directed or undirected graphs. So, some experimentation may be necessary too.